# How to create pagination for html table with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have a html table and need to create pagination for it using the Bootstrap library and JQuery.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
     <thead>
     <tr>
       @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns) 
        {
           <th>@column.ColumnName</th>
        }
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
       {
          <tr>
          @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
          {
              <td>@row[column].ToString()</td>   
          }
          </tr>                             
        }
        </tbody>
</table>
```

I need pagination for every 20 items in the table. Should be numbered. thanks

Comment: If you can afford another plugin look into Datatables.js. It allows you to do so much more than simple paging.

Comment: Robert the site does not give an example with a html table. Smith I need it with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I use [jPaginate](http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/) on a site when i paginate a table with a lot of elements - Give your table body an id then run .jPaginate() like so

```
$('#your_id').jPaginate();
```

You can probably do the same with the bootstrappaginator that @Robert Harvey mentioned, it's probably a bit more up to date as well.

*edit*
It shouldn't take much to alter the styling of some of the plugins that handle pagination, most of the time you can substitute the class names they provide, drop their css and use bootstrap pagination css classes instead.